# Using Kendo MVC Grid .Read method how can I pass parameter value to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I'm using Kendo MVC Grid and I've set the .Read method to use the HttpRouteURL:

```
.Read(read => read.Url(Url.HttpRouteUrl("ApiAction", new { controller = "ideationapi", action = "getrequests"}))
```

I need to pass a parameter value to the controller named "MyRequests". I've tried using the

```
.Data("window.procomRequest.getMyRequestsVal"))
```

That does successfully call the JS function and does return the value:

```
    getMyRequestsVal: function () {
        return {
            MyRequests: $("#MyRequestsHidden").prop("value")
        }
    }
```

The issue is that the value never gets to the Conroller method (the MyRequests parameter is always false even when I confirm in the JS function that it should be true):

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public async Task<DataSourceResult> GetRequests([System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBinder(typeof(WebApiDataSourceRequestModelBinder))] DataSourceRequest request, bool MyRequests = false)
    {
        (SOME CODE HERE)
        var rResult = result.ToDataSourceResult(request);
        return rResult;
    }
```

I believe it's because it's using the route table but I'm not sure how/what to modify to make it work.

I've also tried adding a parameter to the .Read (and removing the .Data) but it's hard code and I need it to be true/false based on the value of a checkbox on the page:

```
                .Read(read => read.Url(Url.HttpRouteUrl("ApiAction", new { controller = "ideationapi", action = "getrequests", MyRequests = true })))
```

Any help is appreciated.